# Which button is pressed in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I have a view with an `ExpandableListView` which has the following view as its header view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#ffa500"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_weight="8" android:text="text" android:background="#ffa500"
            android:focusable="false" android:onClick="openChildDialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The method `openChildDialog` is being called when I press the button. However, since there would be many instances of this button based on the number of list headers, how do I know which instance of the button is pressed?

**EDIT**: The aim here is that, since every `TextView` has a `Button`, based on which button is pressed, I want to get the text of its corresponding `TextView`.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use `getGroupView()` method, you can set tag to your button to retrieve and detect it later.

If you show your code, I will provide more infomation.

an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/31050712/1979882

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that you need that (please let me know what you want to do after identifying the button), but if you really want to identify the button pressed you can assign a unique an unique integer or String to each button after you inflate it in your adapter class using `setTag(Object object)` and later in `openChildDialog()` method you can get back the value using `getTag()` on that view method.

make sure you assign the value to the button, not the entire item's view.